# Replace iframe video player with link to target page

Tags: html, youtube

I would like to modify my current code so that instead of the whole player, display only link to it. Does anyone have an idea how to do it? I have something like this:

```
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>" style="border: 0; width: 100%; height: 360px;" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

And I want something like this:

```
"U can watch this here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>"
```

Comment: This  is not related to php. It's an html question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a "link" with an "anchor" (`<a>`) tag.  Something like this:

```
U can watch this here: <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>">http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?></a>
```

Or simply:

```
U can watch this here: <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>">Click here!</a>
```

Comment: You should add the attribute: `target="_blank"` to open in a new tab/window

Comment: @petebolduc: That's certainly an option, as are many other possible options of things the OP may possibly want to do.  But where is that mentioned in the actual question?

Comment: @petebolduc This attribute is also helpful, thanks :)

Comment: I had the same answer you provided with the target option suggested as it is always nice to keep the our pages opened in the user's browser... when i saw you had answered the question i simply made the suggestion in the comments here... getting a little bit picky here aren't we.

Comment: @petebolduc: While using the `target` attribute is certainly *possible*, whether or not it's *preferable* is entirely a matter of opinion.  (And an opinion I don't share.  I personally find it annoying when a website keeps opening tabs for no reason.)  More to the point, it has nothing to do with the question being asked.  Staying on-topic isn't really "picky".  If the question is "How do I make a link in HTML?" then "Links should always open new tabs in my opinion" isn't really an answer.

Comment: @David... i like you find it annoying when a site opens internal pages in new tabs, but in this case the user is being brought off site where it is good practice in my opinion to keep my site up. regarding the rest... how often to you see the suggestion to make use of pdo to prevent mysql injections when that is not part of the question? I was not attempting to correct you in any manner... my comment was pointed to the inquirer, who, did find it helpful... we all make use of this site to both learn and share... have a good day

Answer (score 0):

Use an `a` tag:

`"U can watch this here: <a href='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>'>Video</a>"`

Comment: You should add the attribute: `target="_blank"` to open in a new tab/window